# Configure embedded Jetty in Hadoop

Tags: jsp, hadoop, web, jetty

There's an embedded Jetty in Hadoop.

I wish to add a new web application to - for example - `localhost:50077`, where my custom JSP would run. How and where can I configure the embedded Jetty in Hadoop to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded Jetty is done, typically, in code.

You'll need to modify the code in Hadoop itself to add your extra WebAppContext for your JSP content.  Don't forget to add all of the JSP dependencies to Hadoop too.

Note, that you have several different hadoop run Jetty servers, so you'll need to understand Hadoop really well to know where to add these features.  Also note that Hadoop is running Jetty 6.x and has not upgraded past that version.

Be sure you test this out extensively, as the extra burden of JSP startup might throw off the timing for Hadoop.